# Scala akka typed: how to get ActorRef to Actor from it's instance and send message itself?

Tags: scala, reference, akka, actor, self

I want to send message from Actor instance (case class/class from what it's behaviour created) to it's Actor.

I gain it by saving instance, and then save `ActorRef` in it:

```
val (instance, behaviour) = MyActorInstance(Nothing)
val actor = ActorSystem(instance, "SomeName123")
//save it here
instance.setMyActor(actor)

object MyActorInstance {
  def apply(ctx: ActorContext[Commands]): (MyActorInstance,Behavior[Commands]) = {
    val actorInstance = new MyActorInstance(ctx)
    val behaviour: Behavior[Commands] =
      Behaviors.setup { context =>
        {
          Behaviors.receiveMessage { msg =>
            actorInstance.onMessage(msg)
          }
        }
      }
    (actorInstance,behaviour)
  }
}

class MyActorInstance(context: ActorContext[Commands]) extends AbstractBehavior[Commands](context) {

  protected var myActorRef: ActorRef[Commands] = null

  def setMyActor(actorRef: ActorRef[Commands]): Unit = {
    myActorRef = actorRef
  }

  override def onMessage(msg: Commands): Behavior[Commands] = {
    msg match {
      case SendMyself(msg) =>
        myActorRef ! IAmDone(msg)
        Behaviors.same
      case IAmDone(msg) =>
        println(s"Send $msg to myself!")
        Behaviors.same
    }
  }
}
```

Here i save `ActorRef` to Actor for it's instance in `var myActorRef`. 
Then i use that `myActorRef` to send message from Actor's instance to itself by `SendMyself` message.

But for that, as you see, i am using variables, which is not good: to save `ActorRef` it's need to rewrite field `myActorRef` of instance of `MyActorInstance` class from `null` to `ActorRef` - it is possible only with **var**iables.

If I try to use val and create immutable class by rewriting its instance for new, and then swap it from old to new, my Actor `actor` still linked to old instance where `myActorRef == null`.

Now I found one way: just using `var` instead of `val` or immutable class.

But I want to use val or nothing.
For that I need to get ActorRef from it's instance, but how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason for such complex dance, just use `ctx.self`. And please read at least the most basic documentation before asking, it would even have saved you time.